# Add whitespace to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Simply put, I want to split a string in javascript into an array, which should also include all the whitespaces in the original string.

Ex: `"Hi There"` should be broken down to `['H','i',' ','T','h','e','r','e']`
I tried using `str.split('')` only to find the results as `['H','i','','T','h','e','r','e']`
I want a whitespace after `"i"` in `"Hi"` here in this example

Comment: No, that is not the result of `"Hi There".split("")`. It works as intended in this case. But `Array.from("Hi There")` does it correctly for all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const result = "Hi There".split(""),
      solution = [..."Hi There"];
      

console.log(result);
console.log(solution);
```

Comment: Thanks, you made this easy for me. I actually wanted this to use in a char animation with react trails, though it didnot work there, I actually learned a cool way for string conversions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same as yours, and it worked, i.e.`"Hi There".split('')` gives a space where it finds one:

```js
console.log("Hi There".split(''))
```

Comment: Yah, I just realized this, actually the problem was with react useTrails, it was not parsing the whitespaces and kept on ignoring them. So, in my final animation, all the whitespaces were missing. Thanks for the answer anyways